# Activity report showing activities twice

Tags: civireport

[image]All of my activity reports have recently changed to return two entries for the same activity. I have looked under sorting and columns and filters, but cannot seem to disable the double entries. Please see a screen shot of a report which shows details from phone call activities. 
This is happening for ALL activity type reports, so changing the particular activity makes no difference. On civi 5.4.0

I have added some more screen shots - hopefully this answers questions? many thanks. Also, I am using sort criteria as date and it makes no difference if I change filter for Limit to current User as Yes or No.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's showing a listing for the 'reporter' and the 'with' contact separately (not ideal obviously, just working on debugging). Is that the case? - I can't remember what the headings are off the top of my head.

Comment: Could you edit your question to list the criteria (columns, sorting, filters) that you have set for this report?  Or take a screenshot that includes this information.  That could help to determine what the issue is.